# Missing dependency: openpyxl in VS Studio

Tags: python, openpyxl, economics

Whenever I try to run my code in VS Studio, it says 'Exception has occurred: ImportError
Missing optional dependency 'openpyxl'.  Use pip or conda to install openpyxl.'

I have tried running pip install and selecting a different interpreter, but it still doesn't work.

```
import pandas as pd 
# read data from excel 
data = pd.read_excel("a-millennium-of-macroeconomic-data-for-the-uk.xlsx", sheet_name = 'A1. Headline series', header = 3, usecols = 'A,AP,AT')
# clean data for plotting
data = data.drop(0,1,2,)
data.columns = ['Year', 'CPI_inflation', 'Short_term_rate']
data.CPI_inflation=pd.to_numeric(data.CPI_inflation)
data.Short_term_rate = pd.to_numeric(data.Short_term_rate)
data_plot = data(data.Year >= 1930)

# plotting

plot = data_plot.plot( x = 'Year', y = ["CPI_inflation", 'Short_term_rate'], title = "Historical CPI-Inflation and Short Term Rates")
plot.set_ylabel('%')
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to help you troubleshoot without more information about your current setup, python version etc. Are you using a virtual environment?

Comment: I think it's Python 3.11.1 64-bit and I'm just using Python in VS Studio. I've now added the code I'm referring to as well!

Comment: in Solution Explorer (right side by default) you have Python 3.11 (64-bit) (global default) or something similar. Open it and see is pandas here or not.

Comment: **selecting a different interpreter** how did you do that?

Comment: It says Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages (1.5.3) and pandas is in the solution explorer

Comment: The different interpreter was >Python>Select Interpreter and there were 2 options

Comment: You are showing the message *Requirement already satisfied: pandas ...* however it is now Openpyxl that you should be installing with pip. Openpyxl is not installed by Pandas